# How Do I Convert A String Into a Number in SAS?

Tags: string, sas, type-conversion, proc-sql

I'm pretty new to SAS and struggling with the type conversions. They seem to be anything but intuitive to me. *I need to do this within SAS PROC SQL statements.*

Can someone help me figure out the best way to convert a field that is formatted like the below into a number so it can have some addition/subtraction performed and be compared to a numerical field?

Field format example: '      +3,820.00'

I've used strip() to get rid of the + sign, comma, and spaces and then input() to make it a number, but I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `commaw.d` informat will deal with all of that without any stripping/etc.  It happily takes the + sign as positive and the comma/decimal.  This works in SQL as well, but easier to show example as below...

```
data _null_;
  x=' +3,820.00';
  y=input(x,comma12.);
  put x= y=;
run;
```

Comment: Joe, perhaps going into a little more detail about how type conversions work might be in order seeing as the asker is confused as to how they operate.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure exactly what you're thinking here.  Are you talking something like describing how an informat is a template to convert a "pretty" variable to a number?

Comment: Just the basics to help someone new move in the right direction.  I'd consider discussing the difference between input and put, formats and informats, and where they can go to find more help/info.  While some of this may not directly answer the asker's question, future visitors may benefit from it (and we may get less conversion questions on SO =P   )

Answer (score 1):

use compress rather than strip

field1=input(compress(field,'+,'),6.);

or

field1=input(compress(field,'+,'),comma10.2)format=comma10.2;

Answer (score 1):

The input is the proper way to convert strings to numerics and you can use input in proc sql select statements (See [character to numeric conversion while sql extracting](https://communities.sas.com/message/198422) for example).  There are informats that you can pass to the input function that will help you with commas & signs so that you don't have to strip them out prior to calling input.  More information can be found here: [Informats by Category](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001239776.htm).

If this doesn't help, please let me know.